# iptables one connection from external IP

Tags: ubuntu

I want to be able to connect to my server from outside my office, but I want make just one person can use remote desktop at once

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp  -s 00.00.00.00 -d $INET_IP --dport 1122 \
 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3344
```

What I have to add to make it work, and is it possible using iptables?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict your rule based on the source IP address, you need to specify the IP address in the `-s source_ip` option.

Also, you need to make sure the needed port is allowed in the `INPUT` chain (access to local host) or `FORWARD` chain (access to another machine via firewall).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the possible connections to one, connlimit is your friend. Make sure to limit on the destination, not the source, as you'll just limit everyone who wants to connect to one connection, instead of just one person at a time connectivity.